# React. Функция не видит изменение state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Дефолтное значение стейта orders - `{ orders: [] }`

Каждую секунду я через сокет отправляю запрос на получение новых заказов, данные передаются в функцию `setOrdersListner`, которая должна сравнивать длину массива orders.orders и длину массива response.orders для обнаружения новых заказов, по факту в функциях `setOrdersListner` и колбэке `checkLength` стейт orders всегда равен значению инициализации `{ orders: [] }`, из-за чего `checkLength` всегда возвращает `True`, что является некорректным поведением.

Далее по приложению стейт `orders` считывается корректно, значит `setOrders` в функции `setOrdersListner` работает корректно. React DevTools так же подтверждает что `orders` изменяется.

Прошу у Вас помощи в решении проблемы.

**React DevTools**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Консоль ( слева response, справа orders)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Код**

```
const [orders, setOrders] = useState({orders: []});

const checkLength = useCallback((response) => response.orders.length > orders.orders.length, [orders]);

const setOrdersListner = (response) => {
    if (checkLength(response)){
        setOrders(response);
        console.log(response, orders);
    }
  };

useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("sendingNotCompleted", setOrdersListner);
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval( () => {
        if (socket){
            socket.emit('fetchNotCompleted')
        }
    }, 1000)
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Вставьте пожалуйста минимальный воспроизводимый код React: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12004/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%a4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-stack-snippet-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-react-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-jsx

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалось в том, как я понял, при первой отрисовке в `socket.emit` передавалась функция, знающая только текущее состояние стейта.
Решено добавлением очистки в `useEffect` и добавлением `депса` для обновления.

```
const setOrdersListner = (response) => {
        if (checkLength(response)){
            console.log(response, orders);
            setOrders(response);
        }
      };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on("sendingNotCompleted", setOrdersListner);

        return function cleanup (){
            socket.removeAllListeners('sendingNotCompleted');
            console.log('listners cleanup')
        }
    }, [orders])
```